# C++/CLI pin_ptr

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Is C++/CLI's [pin_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the equivalent of C#'s [fixed statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pretty much.

Some differences:

1. A `fixed` statement creates its own scope block. `pin_ptr`'s scope is from its initialization to the 
   end of the enclosing block.
2. `fixed` is an explicit language feature. <strike>`pin_ptr` is a use of a general language feature (C++ templates).</strike>(See comments.)

There are probably more differences like the above. But, when translating between the two languages, they are generally equivalent.

Comment: Like dynamic_cast, pin_ptr is a language feature using the same syntax as a template.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. Your point is well taken. I'll not try to make a distinction between a language and it's only implementation.

Comment: Well, it's not possible to implement it as a template, at least not if you want to correctly enforce all the rules (for example, the documentation specifies that "Pinning pointers can only be declared as non-static local variables on the stack.").