# Is it possible to create pinned pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, c++-cli

Is it possible to create pinned pointer in `C#` like a `pin_ptr` in `C++/CLI`?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037077/c-cli-pin-ptr

Comment: Only for arrays of some struct types (`int`, `uint`, `short`, `ushort`, `IntPtr`...) and for `string`s

Comment: The exact equivalent of pin_ptr<> in C# code is the `fixed` keyword.  It is not the same thing as a pinned pointer, it uses a far more optimized way to tell the GC to not move the object.  Simply a status bit in the metadata that the jitter generates, there is no underlying CLR call.  But you have to be careful, the pointer becomes invalid as soon as execution leaves the fixed statement.

Comment: @HansPassant `pin_ptr` is more powerful than `fixed`. With `pin_ptr` you can pin anything, while with `fixed` you can pin only some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The general solution:**

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myObject, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    IntPtr myPinnedPointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    // use myPinnedPointer for your needs
}
finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
```

**Special cases:**

If your object is an array of a struct or is a string, *and* you are allowed to used unsafe code in your project, you can use the `fixed` context:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (char* myPinnedPointer = myString)
    {
        // use myPinnedPointer for your needs
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a `myObject = new object()` see what happens :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Object contains no data, so there is no meaning to access its content via a fixed pointer. And `myObject` is not allowed to contain other reference types, too. So this works only for objects with blittable members, of course.

Comment: the point was exactly that *is not allowed to contain other reference types* (and is not permitted to be a reference type I would add, other than an array or a `string`)

Answer (score 1):

While in C# there is the `fixed` keyword, and you can use the `System.GCHandle` struct, there is nothing that has the "power" of `pin_ptr<>`. With `pin_ptr<>` you can pin any managed object, while with `fixed` you are limited to pinning `string`s or array of value types that don't contain reference types. So you can pin an `int[]`, or a `MyEnum[]`, or a `MyStructWithoutReferenceTypes[]`, but not a `MyClassType` or a `MyClassType[]`.

Comment: pin_ptr<> has no extra magic, it still needs to be a blittable value type.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure of this? Because `pin_ptr<List<String^>^> pinned(&obj)` compiles and runs.

Comment: @HansPassant From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx): *An object or sub-object of a managed class can be pinned, in which case the common language runtime will not move it during garbage collection*

Comment: Hmya, it compiles but what are you going to do next?  You can't do anything with that pointer.

Comment: @HansPassant It is pinned, so I can put it in a normal pointer and pass it around. The point isn't doing the `&` to take the address (you can do it without the `pin_ptr` in C++/CLI), it is to force the GC to not move the object, so that the pointer I took remains valid.

Comment: A pointer that you can't dereference is like a boomerang that doesn't come back.  It is a stick.

Comment: @HansPassant you can cast a `void*` to `interior_ptr<SomeManagedType^>` then dereference that. It works, [I use it in a project of mine](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net/blob/master/src/PCRE.NET.Wrapper/MatchContext.cpp#L43)